# How can I assign different colors to comments and nested comments in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

So Docs has [this great feature](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/65129?hl=en) which I have begun using heavily and I would like to do something more with it.  Right now, all text in a document that I have attached comments to are the same light yellow.  When a bit of text with an attached comment is selected, it turns bold yellow unless it is a nested comment and then it remains the same light yellow.

I would like to possibly be able to assign different highlight colors to comments.  I think this would be particularly beneficial in the case of nested comments.

Here's an example:

> This entire sentence is highlighted the same light yellow (and here's a parenthetical remark that also has its own nested comment) because it has an attached comment.

Is this possible?  Should I submit a feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible, but you can [submit your idea](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!categories/docs/docs-community).

Comment: [Done!](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/docs/docs-community/SrDj6tcOc0Q)